# Android Retrofit library always returns null

Tags: java, android, null, retrofit

I am trying to communicate with the server with Retrofit, but I always get null reference.

The API: http://gaborbencebekesi.hu/vote/api/get/questions

In the application I have a model class:

public class Question {

```
public String question;
public String uploader;
public boolean password;
public String url;

public Question(String question, String uploader, boolean password, String url) {
    this.question = question;
    this.uploader = uploader;
    this.password = password;
    this.url = url;
}
```

}

and a network class.

public class Network {

```
private final String API_URL = "http://gaborbencebekesi.hu/vote/";

private Retrofit retrofit;

private interface Questions {
    @GET("api/get/questions/")
    Call<List<Question>> get();
}

public Network() {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public List<Question> GetQuestions() throws IOException {

    // Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
    Questions questions = retrofit.create(Questions.class);

    // Create a call instance for looking up Retrofit contributors.
    Call<List<Question>> call = questions.get();

    // Fetch and print a list of the contributors to the library.
    List<Question> q = call.execute().body();
    if(q == null) System.err.println("list is null");
    return q;

}
```

}

last function always returns null.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: What is in your Questions.java file? (not Question.java)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this because you are making this call on the main thread. Do something like this:

```
public void GetQuestions() throws IOException {

    // Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
    Questions questions = retrofit.create(Questions.class);

    // Create a call instance for looking up Retrofit contributors.
    Call<List<Question>> call = questions.get();

    // Fetch and print a list of the contributors to the library.
    call.enqueue(this);
}
```

You should implement the callbacks and handle the response in the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using synchronous call, please use asynchronous call, So please change your code

```
Call<List<Question>> call = questions.get();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Question>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Question>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<Question>> response) {
                if (response.body != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body.size(); i++)
                        log.e("response", response.body.get(i));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Question>> call, Throwable t) {
                  //handle fail
            }
        });
```